# Why does the entity type '' require a primary key to be defined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'MyType' requires a primary key to be defined

Trying to use DbContext, DbSet etc.

I don't think `MyType` does need a primary key though?

Why am I being told to give it a primary key...

I have created some models that look like

```
public ContainerType
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public int SomeData { get; set; }

  public MyType Foo { get; set; }
  public MyType Bar { get; set; }
}

public MyType
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public List<OtherType> OtherTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and I try to create a `DbSet<ContainerType> Items`, but whenever I do `Items.Count()` I am getting that `InvalidOperationException`.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an "entity" is an object that has an identifier, in contrast to a "value object", where the identity of is the sum total of all its data. For example, you could have a class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

However, multiple people could have the same name, so the mere values of `FirstName` and `LastName` is not enough to uniquely identify a person. You need an explicit identifier:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can distinguish between two different people with the same name.

There's no coincidence that EF is *Entity* Framework. It's literally a framework for working with entities, i.e. objects with identifiers. That's your PK, and it is *required* for all entities, or else they would not in fact be entities.

If you truly feel you don't need PKs (though I would consider that assumption suspect), then EF is not the right solution for you. You might instead want to use `IDistributedCache`, `Session`, or a NoSQL store. Either of those will allow you work with any form of data you like (though you will need to serialize to/from JSON). However, you'll likely find that you'll still need ids of some sort or another.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think MyType does need a primary key though?

You need a `Key` attributed (assuming you're using DataAnnotations) property on each class that part of your EF models. This is required to set up the foreign key relationships in the underlying relational database.

> whenever I do Items.Count() I am getting that InvalidOperationException

Do you only get this error on `.Count()` or do all of your operations on this DbSet throw the same exception due to an invalid model?

Comment: Probably all, I only tried using `.Count()` so far. Why do I need a `Key` attributed property on every class in my EF models?

Comment: To facilitate the relationships between your database records.

Comment: even though in my models they're just properties and lists? why can't it add the primary keys itself if it needs to create some relational db... I won't use them...

Comment: Maybe i am using the wrong thing for storage, I just copied some sample code and tried to repurpose it. I guess I shouldn't be using a DbContext here?